# How to access a value within a nested json file based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on a project where I need to access data from api's. In these api's are values named 'decimal' which I need to access. I have no problem accessing and displaying the decimal value itself, but when I try to only display decimal value based on another value within the json I seem to struggle. My code currently looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as r

api = 'https://content.toto.nl/content-service/api/v1/q/event-list?startTimeFrom=2024-03-31T22%3A00%3A00Z&startTimeTo=2024-04-01T21%3A59%3A59Z&started=false&maxMarkets=10&orderMarketsBy=displayOrder&marketSortsIncluded=--%2CCS%2CDC%2CDN%2CHH%2CHL%2CMH%2CMR%2CWH&marketGroupTypesIncluded=CUSTOM_GROUP%2CDOUBLE_CHANCE%2CDRAW_NO_BET%2CMATCH_RESULT%2CMATCH_WINNER%2CMONEYLINE%2CROLLING_SPREAD%2CROLLING_TOTAL%2CSTATIC_SPREAD%2CSTATIC_TOTAL&eventSortsIncluded=MTCH&includeChildMarkets=true&prioritisePrimaryMarkets=true&includeCommentary=true&includeMedia=true&drilldownTagIds=691&excludeDrilldownTagIds=7291%2C7294%2C7300%2C7303%2C7306'
re = r.get(api)
red = re.json()

#Finding the 'type' variable within the Json file
match_result = pd.json_normalize(red, record_path=['data', 'events', 'markets', 'outcomes'])
match_result = match_result['type']

#For every type variable within the file we check if type == 'MR'
for type in match_result:
    if type == 'MR':  
        #If the type == 'MR' I want to print the decimal belonging to that type value but this is where i'm doing something wrong
        decimal = pd.json_normalize(match_result, record_path=['prices'])
        decimal = decimal['decimal']
        print(decimal)
    else:
        pass
```

I've been looking all over youtube and stackoverflow to find what im doing wrong but can't seem to figure it out. Also important to note is that in the variable 'match_result' I access the type by using the record_path, but for the 'decimal variable' I need to go further into the record path with using 'prices' in the for loop. This is where I think i'm doing it wrong, but still no idea what it is i'm doing wrong.

The Json file from which I want to get the data looks something like this:

```
            "type": "MR",
            "subType": "D",

            #Some more data I wont need....

            "lateVoid": false,
            "outcomeScore": null,
            "prices": [
              {
                "numerator": 13,
                "denominator": 4,
                "decimal": 4.25,
                "displayOrder": 1,
                "priceType": "LP",
                "handicapLow": null,
                "handicapHigh": null
```

Comment: Can u provide dummy JSON so I can take a look. I can't get access that, so if u can provide I'd be happy to help

Comment: Incidentally, be careful with the names of your variables. E.g., `type` is a built-in function (you've guessed it: to check the type of an object). You're overwriting it, which may lead to tricky errors when you want to use the built-in function later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use indexing with dataframe object match_result. To get the decimals use: `match_result['prices'][i][0]['decimal']`. To get the type use: `match_result['type'][i]`

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as r

api = 'https://content.toto.nl/content-service/api/v1/q/event-list?startTimeFrom=2024-03-31T22%3A00%3A00Z&startTimeTo=2024-04-01T21%3A59%3A59Z&started=false&maxMarkets=10&orderMarketsBy=displayOrder&marketSortsIncluded=--%2CCS%2CDC%2CDN%2CHH%2CHL%2CMH%2CMR%2CWH&marketGroupTypesIncluded=CUSTOM_GROUP%2CDOUBLE_CHANCE%2CDRAW_NO_BET%2CMATCH_RESULT%2CMATCH_WINNER%2CMONEYLINE%2CROLLING_SPREAD%2CROLLING_TOTAL%2CSTATIC_SPREAD%2CSTATIC_TOTAL&eventSortsIncluded=MTCH&includeChildMarkets=true&prioritisePrimaryMarkets=true&includeCommentary=true&includeMedia=true&drilldownTagIds=691&excludeDrilldownTagIds=7291%2C7294%2C7300%2C7303%2C7306'
re = r.get(api)
red = re.json()

match_result = pd.json_normalize(red, record_path=['data', 'events', 'markets', 'outcomes'])

for i, v in match_result.iterrows():
    if  match_result['type'][i] == 'MR':
        print(match_result['prices'][i][0]['decimal']) 
        # To print decimal use: match_result['prices'][i][0]['decimal']
        # To print type use:  match_result['type'][i]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

- Use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) with 'type' as metadata (include the same levels except 'prices').

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(red, 
                       record_path=['data', 'events', 'markets', 'outcomes', 'prices'], 
                       meta=[['data', 'events', 'markets', 'outcomes', 'type']]
                       )

df.head()

   numerator  denominator  decimal  displayOrder priceType handicapLow  \
0         13            4     4.25             1        LP        None   
1         63          100     1.63             1        LP        None   
2          4            1     5.00             1        LP        None   
3         11           10     2.10             1        LP        None   
4         13           20     1.65             1        LP        None   

  handicapHigh data.events.markets.outcomes.type  
0         None                                MR  
1         None                                MR  
2         None                                MR  
3         None                                --  
4         None                                --
```

- Now, use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to get back all the values from column 'decimal' where our meta column equals 'MR'.

```py
meta_col = 'data.events.markets.outcomes.type'

decimals = df.loc[df[meta_col].eq('MR'), 'decimal']

decimals.head(5)

0     4.25
1     1.63
2     5.00
20    3.40
21    2.40
Name: decimal, dtype: float64
```

Here the index values (`0, 1, 2, 20, 21`) refer to the rows where 'type' equals 'MR'.